Efficient/fast way to store array of tuples?
I'm storing items that are tied to a time of day associated with an "impact".
For example, an item might have one or more tuples of
(8:30 AM, "High"),
(8:30 AM, "Medium"),
(9:30 AM, "High"),
(10:00 AM, "Medium")

The quick-and-dirty solution was to store this as a string, like:
0830-H_0830-M_0930-H_1000-M

... but that causes some problems when trying to to determine if an item contains/excludes one more given time tuples (and probably doesn't perform well compared to the alternatives).
What's the proper way to go about storing this efficiently for querying in ClickHouse?
There aren't too many variations of this data - perhaps a couple dozen or so (if even that much).
Examples of required queries are:
Select items where item has only 8:30 AM High and 9:30 AM High (8:30 AM Medium and 10:00 AM Medium are allowed)

Select items where item has only 8:30 AM High and 9:30 AM High (8:30 AM Medium and 10:00 AM Medium are not allowed)

Select items where item has only 8:30 AM High and 9:30 AM High (10:00 AM High is not allowed)


You can use array of a tuple and then filter by arrayExists function.
Setup tables
CREATE TABLE your_table_name                                                                                                                                                                 
(                                                                                                                                                                                            
    `name` String,                                                                                                                                                                           
    `records` Array(Tuple(DateTime, String))                                                                                                                                                 
)                                                                                                                                                                                            
ENGINE = MergeTree                                                                                                                                                                           
ORDER BY name  

 INSERT INTO your_table_name (name, records) VALUES                                                                                                           
    ('foo', [('2024-08-07 08:00:00', 'High'), ('2024-08-07 09:00:00', 'Low')]),                                                                                                              
    ('bar', [('2024-08-07 08:00:00', 'Medium'), ('2024-08-07 09:00:00', 'Low')]),                                                                                                            
    ('baz', [('2024-08-07 10:00:00', 'Low')])

Make some queires using arrayExists
FROM your_table_name
WHERE arrayExists(x -> x.2 = 'Low', records) and arrayExists(x -> x.1 < toDateTime('2024-08-07 10:00:00'), records)

SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
WHERE arrayExists(x -> ((x.2) = 'Low'), records) AND arrayExists(x -> ((x.1) < toDateTime('2024-08-07 10:00:00')), records)

Query id: 0247e4ae-9452-47d9-8131-4c841cde1cc3

   ┌─name─┬─records──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
1. │ bar  │ [('2024-08-07 08:00:00','Medium'),('2024-08-07 09:00:00','Low')] │
2. │ foo  │ [('2024-08-07 08:00:00','High'),('2024-08-07 09:00:00','Low')]   │
   └──────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


Not sure how I missed that in the docs... thank you!
